# Multiple filtered get request to my express backend [MERN (React + Express)]

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I have a MERN web app and I'm implementing some get method to get the same item on different occasions. Now when I try to implement a second filter method and pass an existing param in my item schema, Postman sends me back an empty array. [I pass the param in Postman as I make in the first method `GET -> HTTP://localhost:5001/api/rooms/THE_USER_ID`]

Is it possible to make something like this??

```js
//@action GET api/rooms/:where
//@descr GET filtered search rooms
//@access Public
router.get("/:where", (req, res) => {
  Room.find({
    where: req.params.where,
  })
    .then((room) => res.json(room))
    .catch((err) => res.status(404).json({ success: false }));
});

//@action GET api/rooms/:user_id
//@descr GET filtered rooms for user dashboard
//@access Private
router.get("/:user_id", auth, (req, res) => {
  Room.find({
    user_id: req.params.user_id,
  })
    .then((room) => res.json(room))
    .catch((err) => res.status(404).json({ success: false }));
});
```

The second Room.find has to be private in my case, but I tried it public and it doesn't work either. I tried also to change the param, but it doesn't work.
Could anyone please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine you're the router. You see a request: `/api/rooms/1`. How do you know which handler to call - does `1` mean `:where` or `:user_id`? They have the same routing pattern - both listen to `/api/rooms/<something>`.

You should have two separate routes instead, so that it's possible to tell them apart - for example, `/api/rooms/by-where/:where` and `/api/rooms/by-user/:user_id`.